# Generate a list with all possible substitutions

Tags: algorithm, replace, lua

I don't really know how to title this question, but this is what I'm trying to implement:

**A function that takes a string and returns a list with all possible combinations for replacing occurrences of `!` in that string with `Any`.**

Example:

```
gen_combinations('(test ! with !)')
=> {
    '(test ! with !)',
    '(test Any with !)',
    '(test Any with Any)',
    '(test ! with Any)'
}
```

Comment: I guess you will need to tokenize the input string and then use a recursive approach to replace the tokens with `any`.

Comment: Even when I can simply call `string:gsub` to replace occurences?

Comment: `(test Any with Any)` this gives me the feeling that you need to have combinations (2^n-1, n being the number of tokens) rather than simply replacing a `token` at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
function gen_combinations(str)
   local res = {}
   local count = 1
   str:gsub("!", 
      function() 
         count = count * 2 
      end
   )
   for mask = 0, count - 1 do
      table.insert(res, (str:gsub("!", 
         function() 
            mask = math.floor(mask) / 2
            if mask % 1 ~= 0 then 
               return "Any" 
            end 
         end
      )))
   end
   return res
end
```